# Converting Azure Cosmos DB graph database to python graph object

Tags: python, azure-cosmosdb, networkx, graph-databases, gremlinpython

I need to run some link prediction models on a graph database using the networkx package in python.  The graph database is currently stored in Azure Cosmos DB.  I have been able to connect to the database using gremlin-python package, but I cannot extract the data in any form that can be converted to a graph object for networkx.  I need the vertices and all of their attributes as well as the edges connecting them.

Here’s what I have so far, which just returns an empty dataframe.  The vertex information will appear in the terminal, but I cannot save it as an object.
How can I extract the data from Cosmos DB into a format that can be converted to a graph object in python?  Thanks.

Code:

```py
from gremlin_python.driver import client, serializer,protocol
import pandas as pd

def get_vertices(client, vertices):
   callback = client.submitAsync(vertices)
   for result in callback.result():
       print("\t{0}".format(result))
 
   return(pd.DataFrame(callback.result()))

   if __name__ == "__main__":

       client = client.Client('<endpoint>','g',
       username=="<username>”
       password="<password>”
 
       message_serializer=serializer.GraphSONSerializersV2d0())

   vertices = "g.V().valueMap().by(unfold()).toList()"

   Vdata = get_vertices(client, vertices)
   print(Vdata.head())
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the specific issue in your above code is how you are accessing the result. You are using `callback.result()` where you might need to be doing something like `callback.result().all().result()`. callback is a [future](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-cosmos-db-graph-python-getting-started/blob/master/connect.py) and you are correctly getting the result of the future (`.result()`) but that returns a [ResultSet](https://github.com/apache/tinkerpop/blob/master/gremlin-python/src/main/python/gremlin_python/driver/resultset.py) so you need the additional `all().result()` to access what you need.

Azure has some samples and you can see how they access the return results here: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-cosmos-db-graph-python-getting-started/blob/master/connect.py

---

I did this a while back as I wanted to visualise data quickly in Python from CosmosDB. I didn't use Pandas, I directly put the data in a NetworkX graph. I am not sure if this is the most efficient way of going about it but it worked:

1. Create your NetworkX graph `G = nx.DiGraph()`
2. Execute query to get vertices you want from your graph `client.submit(<YOUR GREMLIN VERTEX QUERY e.g. g.V()>)`
3. Iterate over returned result, for each vertex add a node into the NetworkX graph `G.add_node()`

```
    vertices_response = client.submit(<YOUR GREMLIN VERTEX QUERY e.g. g.V()>)
    vertices = vertices_response.all().result()
    for vertex in vertices:
        G.add_node(< Up to you how you transform your data to be represented here. You could explicitly state what fields you need e.g. vertex["id"] >)
```

4. Repeat for edges:

```
    edges_response = client.submit(<YOUR GREMLIN VERTEX QUERY e.g. g.E()>)
    edges = edges_response.all().result()

    for edge in edges:
        logging.debug(edge)
        G.add_edge(edge["inV"], edge["outV"])
```

Note: Mine is slightly different using submit instead of AsyncSubmit but you should be able to get the rough idea

Comment: Hello all, any ideas on how long it takes to build a graph in networkx reading in nodes/edges from cosmos db gremlin api? I am also in a similar situation where I need to experiment with graph algorithms. Gremlin doesn't seems to have many algorithms built-in (cosmos db gremlin is OLTP, i guess). Neo4j GDS is an option but too expensive for me to go that route. 
I am looking to do something like this: 

Cosmos db Gremlin --> Networkx --> Cosmos db Gremlin

Any suggestion is highly appreciated!